# Paquete caret en R y sus predicciones

Tags: r

¿Cómo puedo generar unos intervalos?, puede ser de confianza o de predicción para los modelos que se generan con el paquete Caret en R.

```
plsProbs <- predict(plsFit3x10cv, newdata = testing, type = "prob")
```

Por lo general se puede poner `Interval="Confidence"` u otra cosa, pero con los modelos de este paquete no me funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Laura, puedes acceder directamente al modelo de esta forma `<modelo>$finalModel` y ejecutar `predict` tal como lo vienes haciendo normalmente. Veamos un ejemplo:

```
df <- read.table(text = 'Cobranza Facturacion
100 200
200 400
300 600
100 220
100 210', header=TRUE)

cobranza.lm <- lm(Cobranza ~  Facturacion, data=df)
```

Esto es crear un modelo lineal básico para predecir una cobranza en función a su facturación, ahora si quiero predecir este valor a partir de un dato de facturación de `150$`, podemos hacer esto:

```
newdata <-data.frame(Facturacion = c(150))
predict(cobranza.lm, newdata, interval="predict")
```

Esto nos retornará, el valor y el intervalo pedido:

```
       fit      lwr      upr
1 69.61691 52.76363 86.47019
```

Si usamos el paquete [`caret`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/caret/), se puede hacer lo mismo que pides, pero de forma ligeramente distinta:

```
library("caret")

cobranza.caret.lm <- train(Cobranza ~  Facturacion, data=df, method='lm')
predict(cobranza.caret.lm$finalModel, newdata, interval = "predict")
```

Como puedes ver, construimos el mismo modelo anterior, al que podemos acceder desde **`cobranza.caret.lm$finalModel`**, y usarlo directamente en `predict` tal como hicimos antes. Deberíamos obtener los mismos intervalos:

```
       fit      lwr      upr
1 69.61691 52.76363 86.47019
```

**Nota Importante**: el parámetro `interval` es propio de la Clase del modelo definido, particularmente lo implementan los modelos [`lm`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/lm.html) y [`nls`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/nls.html), para cualquier otro modelo que no lo implemente, el parámetro será ignorado.

Comment: Pero funciona para ese método pero si tengo method="rpart" por ejemplo, no me funciona, no me sale nada

Comment: Me sale este error: Error in predict.randomForest(fit.rf$finalModel, newdata = vaa, interval = "confidence") : 
  variables in the training data missing in newdata

Comment: Laura, con respecto a tu primer comentario, cuando creas un modelo, estas creando un objeto de una clase determinada, `interval` es un parámetro que solo lo implementan ciertas clases, claramente lo tenes en `lm` y `nls`, cualquier otro modelo va a ignorar este parámetro. Ahora edito la pregunta para agregar este comentario.

Comment: El error que mencionas en tu comentario no tiene nada que ver con tu pregunta original, y si con los datos del dataframe `vaa`, te sugiero si quieres que lo enmarques en otra pregunta, agregando especialmente la especificación de los dataframes. Saludos.

Comment: @LauraIsazaEcheverri, revisa mis últimos dos comentarios, cualquier cosa me dices. Saludos.

Comment: Lo entiendo; entonces como hago para crear unos intervalos para esas predicciones (Para cada una)?

Comment: @LauraIsazaEcheverri, si el modelo no implementa estos intervalos, la respuesta rápida sería: no puedes.